# Undefined variable in Js

Tags: javascript

I am new to Js and it is curious why the variable `count` does not work as I expected.

There is **3 variable** `count` and the apparently 1st and 2nd does not work but why ?

**Edit: I am expecting the 1st variable of `count` to be able to access through the function. The reason of the variable `count` is to calculate the total of the result instead of the `.ForEach(item, count)` as it will stop sum up the value of the `count`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//1st Error
//var count = 1;

function run (pagesToScrape) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (!pagesToScrape) {
                pagesToScrape = 1;
            }
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            //2nd Error
            //var count = 1;

            await page.goto("https://news.ycombinator.com/");
            let currentPage = 1;
            let urls = [];
            while (currentPage <= pagesToScrape) {
                let newUrls = await page.evaluate(() => {

                    //Count only work here
                    //Why ?
                    let count = 1;

                    let results = [];
                    let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.storylink');
                    items.forEach((item) => {
                        results.push({
                            index: count,
                            url:  item.getAttribute('href'),
                            text: item.innerText,
                        });
                        count++;
                    });
                    return results;
                });
                //Do smtg
                currentPage++;
            }
            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}

run(5).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Most of your variables are commented out, and you haven't told us what behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think this a scope issue, but you don't need count as forEach already provides an index `forEach((item, index) => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared with `let` and `const` are block-scoped, meaning they are only accessible within the scope you define them.  You will need to define the variable `count` with `var` to set it in the global scope.